# PrimeReact Steps Component how to properly use to pass child component

Tags: reactjs, primereact

i try to use Steps component from PrimeReact and i stuck how to render child component inside Steps base on active index.

```
import { Steps } from "primereact/steps";

const Stepper: React.FC = observer(() => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)
  const toast = useRef<Toast>(null);
  const items = [
    {
      label: "Step0",
      component: <>Hello, I am a component inside of stepper for Step 0</>, How to pass this component?

      command: (event: any) => {
        toast?.current?.show({
          severity: "info",
          summary: "First Step",
          detail: event.item.label,
        });
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Step1",
      component: <>Hello, I am a component inside of stepper for Step 1</>,// how to pass this component?

      command: (event: any) => {
        toast?.current?.show({
          severity: "info",
          summary: "Second Step",
          detail: event.item.label,
        });
      },

    },
    {
      label: "Step2",
      component: <>Hello, I am a component inside of stepper for Step 2</>, // doesn't work on this way
      command: (event: any) => {
        toast?.current?.show({
          severity: "info",
          summary: "Last Step",
          detail: event.item.label,
        });
      },
    },
  ];


  return (
      <div className="card my-3">
        <Toast ref={toast}></Toast>
        <Steps
            model={items}
            activeIndex={activeIndex}
            onSelect={(e) => setActiveIndex(e.index)}
            readOnly={false}
        />
      </div>
  );
});
```

also i try pass child component inside Steps (doesn't work too). But it accept ReactNode as a prop. I cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
<Steps
            model={items}
            activeIndex={activeIndex}
            onSelect={(e) => setActiveIndex(e.index)}
            readOnly={false}
        >
          <>Child Component</> // doesn't work
        </Steps>
```

I can separate Steps from my components and render it using if statement based on active index which i need to share between components but i believe it is not the proper way how to use it out of the box

Comment: I think you have to render the components based on the active index, separately.  I mean not as children but as siblings. you can have another array that keeps step components in order. Then, get the component by the active index (`components[activeIndex]`) and render it after `Steps` component

Comment: in this case i will need to share my state with other components, which is not the way that i wanted

Comment: You are not forced to share states. this component does not accept any property called `component` in `items` list. what you can do is render it after the Steps component: `{items[activeIndex]}`. if you want to share any states, you can use context (or make the `component` property into function components and render them like this (`<ActiveStepComponent prop1={...} prop2={...} />`) which `ActiveStepComponent` is a constant variable that equals to `items[activeIndex]`